# VS 2017 Browser Link Not Working with Static HTML

Tags: asp.net

In an ASP.NET 4.6 project I have followed the instructions for enabling `Browser Link` against a static HTML file (used to bootstrap angular) by entering the following in the proper place in `web.config`.

```
    <add name="Browser Link for HTML" path="*.html" verb="*"
    type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    resourceType="File" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

This is a very simple `web.config` and I am fairly certain it is not an issue of the handler not being added properly as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807441/cant-get-visual-studio-2013-browser-link-working-with-static-html).

However when looking at the html source in the browser, it does not contain the script tags for `Browser Link` described in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link).

I was under the impression that if there was a problem while loading handlers, the application would fail to load.Is there anyway to troubleshoot handlers being loaded in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am developing an Angular module for a CMS, so I was not including the `<body>` tag in my `index.html`.

It turns out, the `<body>` tag **must** be present. I am guessing the handler is using XPATH to insert the `Browser Link` script tags.